# Game Center Not Saving Scores

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

Game Center used to work perfectly a while ago for a different app that I made. However strange things are happening with my current one for about two weeks now.

Uploading and download report no error and I can see my score fine. But if I stop play my game and then 6 hours later come back to it, my score is no longer there in the game center. I mean, literally no score at all. Downloading from game center which works 6 hours ago now cannot retrieve my score.

Game center status is live. I can see my score and others in "manage score" section. However, I cannot see anything except my score in the leaderboard from `GKGameCenterViewController`.

As far as I'm concern, everything has been configured correctly. Game Center in app's capability is on.

Code for showing leaderboard:

```
func showLeaderBoard() {
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated == false {
        self.present(authenticationViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    let gamecenter = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gamecenter.gameCenterDelegate = self
    gamecenter.viewState = .leaderboards
    gamecenter.leaderboardIdentifier = leaderBoardID

    present(gamecenter, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Code for downloading score:

```
func downloadBestScoreFromGameCenter() {
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated == false {return}
    print("Downloading Score...")

    let leaderBoard = GKLeaderboard()
    leaderBoard.identifier = leaderBoardID
    leaderBoard.loadScores(completionHandler: {
        [unowned self] (scores, error) in

        print("Download Error: \(error)")

        scores?.forEach({print("\($0.player?.displayName!) \($0.value)")})

        if let localPlayerScore = leaderBoard.localPlayerScore?.value {
            self.bestScore = Int(localPlayerScore)
            self.saveGameForCurrentState()
        } else {
            self.bestScore = 0
        }
    })
}
```

And uploading

```
func uploadBestScoreToGameCenter() {
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated == false {return}

    let scoreItem = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: leaderBoardID)
    scoreItem.value = Int64(self.bestScore)

    GKScore.report([scoreItem], withCompletionHandler: {
        (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            print("Upload complete: \(scoreItem.value)")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the leaderboard is now working today. I guess you just have to wait people.